# ¿Cómo llamar a un documento externo java script, cuando el html este completamente cargado?

Tags: javascript

por ejemplo:

```
<head>
  <script>
    window.onload = function () {
      <script src="java.js"></script>
    }
  </script>
</head>
```

el codigo de arriba es erroneo, porque no esta permitido meter una etiqueta script dentro de otra, pero me pregunto si habra otra forma de hacer lo que intente arriba, llamar un script cuando el documento se haya cargado completamente.. quiza haya otra sintaxis que no conozco........la otra manera seria meter el script directamente en el evento onload (es decir sin las etiquetas, meter el codigo), pero yo quiero tener mi script en un documento aparte, y a la vez, asegurarme de que se ejecutara cuando el documento este completamente cargado, y no en paralelo...eh ahi el problema

Answer (score -1, accepted):

por que no creas un método y lo llamas en "onload" ?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
 <script src="my_script.js"></script>
 </head>
<body onload="my_function()">

</body>
</html>
```

my_script.js :

```
function my_function () {
    alert("Hello world!");
    }
```

Otra solución escrita en my_script.js :

```
function my_function () {
    alert("Hello world!");
}

document.onload = my_function();
```

Comment: ..........gracias

Answer (score 0):

Puedes simplemente (y recomendado) utilizar el atributo `defer`, simplemente lo agregas a tu `<script>` y este solo se ejecutara hasta que la pagina haya terminado de cargar; por ejemplo:

```
<script src="tu_archivo.js" defer></script>
```

Vale mencionar que el atributo `defer` es especificamente para usar cuando se define un documento externo (como en tu caso); asi que esta es la manera apropiada de detener la ejecucion de tu archivo JavaScript hasta que todo el HTML cargue.

Aqui mas información al respecto (en ingles): [HTML Script defer attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp)

Comment: y en cuanto a compatibilidad con los navegadores desktop y moviles, como está?

Comment: Bastante bueno, todos los navegadores actuales (incluyendo Internet Explorer 10, 11 y 9 parcialmente) lo soportan; la unica excepcion es Opera Mini: https://caniuse.com/#search=defer

Comment: Gracias, he aprendido algo nuevo.Sin embargo ya lo habia hecho de la otra forma que me recomendaron. No obstante la proxima vez optare por esta manera....AUnque no se como resolveria esa incompatibilidad con IE9...Internet explorer 8 e inferiores no me interesan, pero el 9 no se puede ignorar.

Comment: Solo para aclarar, la idea de StackOverflow es promover la mejor informacion que ayude a mas personas a una solucion optima; por ende lo mejor es marcar la respuesta mas optima... Segundo, el caso de IE9 no es que no funcione, simplemente tiene un detalle que preveer, que es que no es bueno usarlo si se trata de 2 scripts que dependen el uno del otro, en cualquier otro caso puedes usarlo en IE9 sin problema alguno: https://github.com/h5bp/lazyweb-requests/issues/42

Comment: @natan si no vas a marcar esta respuesta como correcta al menos dale un voto positivo para que sea mas visible en caso de que alguien mas se tope con la misma pregunta que tu :)

Comment: Pero ya marque la otra, el otro dia...¿se pueden marcar dos a la vez?? Yo pense que ya estaba cerrado este tema.

Comment: No, se puede marcar una respuesta como correcta solamente, pero puedes cambiar cual es la que esta marcada en cualquier momento... Si otras respuestas aportaron algo puedes darle un voto positivo sin marcarla como correcta